# 500 Internal Server Error by PHP Script for permutation

Tags: php, combinations, permutation, internal-server-error

Hi to generate a list of combinations of an array I use this script. My Problem is that I get after some minutes an 500 Internal Server error and I don't know why. The php and mysql timeouts are set to 64000. Perhaps there is an other good solution to generate all combinations. I know that there are lots of combinations. But our Serverhardware is very good, so I think it can't be the problem.

```
    ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 64000);
    ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 64000);

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    set_time_limit(0);
    define("SYS_PATH", "");

function buildCombos($chars, $n)
{
      if ($n <= 0) return array('');

      $built = array();
      foreach ($chars as $char)
            foreach (buildCombos($chars, $n - 1) as $b)
                  $built[] = $b . $char;
      return $built;
}
$chars = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g','h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-'); 
$combo = buildCombos($chars, 4);

foreach ($combo as $key => $inhalt) {
    set_time_limit(0); 
    $domain = $inhalt.'.de'; 

    $dbusername = "xxx";
    $dbdatabase = "xxx";
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbpassword = "xxxx";

    $link = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    mysql_select_db($dbdatabase);

    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");


    mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO de_list SET val = '$domain', val1 = 4, val2 = 0");
    //
    mysql_close($link);
}

echo 'Ready';
```

Comment: **Unrelated:** There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: You don't need to do `SET NAMES` and `SET CHARACTER SET` inside the loop. Just do them once each.

Comment: **Related**: If you need to build these combos, you should rather save them to the database once and for all (using a infinite timeout), or create them in a different language. PHP is one of the slowest languages that exist, and doing this in PHP makes no sense.

Comment: Ok thanks for your comment. I will do it in the future but at the moment it can't be the problem with my script :-)

Comment: @barmer thats right i changed it.

Comment: Check server log for details on the error

Comment: @Mann87 Promise that you'll *actually* do this in the future, or we'll have to tell you again later, and it'll be worse for yourself. There's been way too many "I'll do this later" that never actually do it, and it's getting tiresome to reply with "change to MySQLi or PDO". :-)

Comment: @h2ooooooo I know that php is not the fastest solution but I must do it in php.

Comment: Are any rows getting added to the database? The script might be running out of memory when it tries to create an array of 1.8 million combinations.

Comment: @h2ooooooo yeah I really promise it to you :-)

Comment: @barmar The Server has 128G RAM. The memory_limit is 45G. And the status of server never get more than 20G when it is running.

Comment: @Mann87 If I was you I'd add the items to the database *as soon as you create them* rather than do it later on. That way you should be able to create an offset, if it fails ~30% of the way.

Comment: Are you going to answer my question? Is it dying before adding anything to the DB, or does it get part-way through and then die? The latter sounds like you're running into a time limit -- adding 1.8 million rows to the DB takes a while.

Comment: @barmer it is running for appr. 957.000 combinations. After 8-10 minutes.

Comment: I also looked in the error.log from httpd but I can't find nothing...

Comment: mysqld.log also no problems...

Comment: Can it be that I must set a special query_cache_size or something like that? I also think there must be a limit I forgot.

Comment: Ok now I made an php include of my php file in a new php file and set error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);  and no I see the error Warning: mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104 so I think it is an mysql timeout. Right?